# How do I fix out of bounds geometric extent error?

Tags: postgis, tilemill

I'm new to GIS, and I'm roughly following the instructions here:

http://mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/postgis-work/

to try and import data I obtained from here:

http://factfinder2.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/searchresults.xhtml?refresh=t

into a Postgres database and then query from Tilemill. I'm getting the following error when Tilemill tries to run the query:

```
Detected out of bounds geographic extent (-180,4424208.8281,-13492834.8813,85.051) for layer 'acs'. Please ensure that the SRS for this layer is correct. Its native extent is '-13693889.5411,4424208.8281,-13492834.8813,4566130.4316'
```

Does this error have something to do with the parameter 4269 I used in the following command I used to populate Postgres?:

```
shp2pgsql -s 4269 140_00 census_tracts | /usr/local/bin/psql -d default
```

Answer (score 1):

Your srid is not defined for coordinated you are trying to insert to database. So 4269 is wrong or coordinates are bad data